# always make the expand button at the end of the paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the online sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Nh4K2/

```
<div class="container">
    Nulla varius diam at sem adipiscing pharetra. Integer eget nulla non purus commodo aliquam. Aenean sed nunc neque. Aliquam eleifend aliquam arcu, ac semper nulla faucibus id. Etiam luctus eleifend tempus. Vestibulum ornare, nisi vitae fermentum luctus, sem lectus rhoncus nibh, auctor iaculis magna turpis nec turpis. Aliquam orci tortor, vulputate at pretium sit amet, blandit eget libero. Sed posuere ultricies mi, sed rhoncus massa ultrices quis. Donec pulvinar vestibulum rhoncus. Donec urna lacus, mollis et convallis at, commodo nec lectus. Maecenas pretium, nunc ac volutpat tempus, dolor orci ultricies massa, eu malesuada urna massa ut orci. Duis eget elit nulla, ornare aliquet nulla. Sed eleifend scelerisque est, eu laoreet lacus ultricies id. Aenean aliquam porttitor augue, quis lacinia augue consequat vitae. Ut venenatis orci massa. Duis dignissim, justo at pellentesque adipiscing, ligula eros mollis tellus, ut accumsan lorem dui eu est.
        <div class="whatever">hahahahahaha</div>
    <div class="damn">hohohohohohoho</div>
    <div class="laugh">lololololololololo</div>
</div>
<span>Show</span>​

function excerpt(str, nwords) {
    var words = str.split(' ');
    words.splice(nwords, words.length - 1);
    return words.join(' ') + '&hellip;';
}

var $div = $('.container');
$div.each(function() {
    var theExcerpt = excerpt($(this).text(), 30);
    $(this).data('html', $(this).html()).html( theExcerpt );
});

$('span').click(function() {
    var isHidden = $(this).text() == 'Show';
    var $div = $(this).prev();
    var theExcerpt = excerpt($div.text(), 30);
    $div.html( isHidden ? $div.data('html') : theExcerpt);
    $(this).remove();
});​
```

any possible way to make "show" toggle button always shows at the end of the paragraph?  rather than showing on the second line,  the format looks like

> Nulla varius diam at sem adipiscing pharetra. Integer eget nulla non
>   purus commodo aliquam. Aenean sed nunc neque. Aliquam eleifend aliquam
>   arcu, ac semper nulla faucibus…**Show**

Many thanks for any suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the span to the excerpt in the function.

Make sure you select the span's `parent()` instead of its `prev()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nh4K2/3/

```
<div class="container">
    Nulla varius diam at sem adipiscing pharetra. Integer eget nulla non purus commodo aliquam. Aenean sed nunc neque. Aliquam eleifend aliquam arcu, ac semper nulla faucibus id. Etiam luctus eleifend tempus. Vestibulum ornare, nisi vitae fermentum luctus, sem lectus rhoncus nibh, auctor iaculis magna turpis nec turpis. Aliquam orci tortor, vulputate at pretium sit amet, blandit eget libero. Sed posuere ultricies mi, sed rhoncus massa ultrices quis. Donec pulvinar vestibulum rhoncus. Donec urna lacus, mollis et convallis at, commodo nec lectus. Maecenas pretium, nunc ac volutpat tempus, dolor orci ultricies massa, eu malesuada urna massa ut orci. Duis eget elit nulla, ornare aliquet nulla. Sed eleifend scelerisque est, eu laoreet lacus ultricies id. Aenean aliquam porttitor augue, quis lacinia augue consequat vitae. Ut venenatis orci massa. Duis dignissim, justo at pellentesque adipiscing, ligula eros mollis tellus, ut accumsan lorem dui eu est.
        <div class="whatever">hahahahahaha</div>
    <div class="damn">hohohohohohoho</div>
    <div class="laugh">lololololololololo</div>
</div>
​

function excerpt(str, nwords) {
    var words = str.split(' ');
    words.splice(nwords, words.length - 1);
    return words.join(' ') + '&hellip;' + '<span>Show</span>';
}

var $div = $('.container');
$div.each(function() {
    var theExcerpt = excerpt($(this).text(), 30);
    $(this).data('html', $(this).html()).html( theExcerpt);
});

$('span').click(function() {
    var isHidden = $(this).text() == 'Show';
    var $div = $(this).parent();
    var theExcerpt = excerpt($div.text(), 30);
    $div.html( isHidden ? $div.data('html') : theExcerpt);
    $(this).remove();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the `display` property of `.container` elements to `inline`.

Updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/Nh4K2/2/

If you want them to be block, you could add a wrapper div around both `.container` and the `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is poorly structured, I would lay it out like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="description_text">
        <span>description_text_here</span>
        <span class="show_more"> Show</span>
    </div>
    <div class="more_text_to_show">
        <p>more_text_to_show_here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

At least that is what I am reading into your question and posted code.